# Failed to read key xxxx from store "/Users/liuyue/work/keyStore/CeLueChaoGu.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: android, android-keystore, jarsigner

I met a very stupid and strange question:

```
Failed to read key xxxx from store "/Users/liuyue/work/keyStore/CeLueChaoGu.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect;
```

but, it's different from the other questions, platform is OSX in mac, IDE is android studio, java version is 1.7, the configure above has never changed;

it's **OK** when I make APK by "./gradlew assembleRelease" **in android studio**, 
but it will show me the **error message** when I used "`jarsigner -verbose -keystore <.keystore> -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 <apk file> <alias>`" **in command line**, I'm sure the **password is correct**, so, what should I do?  go die?

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this question!
there are some special characters in my password for high security when I create this keystore, and now it's a stupid decision was confirmed....

there are the right way below:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore <.keystore> -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 <apk file> <alias> -storepass xxxxxx -keypass xxxxx
```

input the command with storepass and keypass, if still error, surround the password with "";

I solved it by this way, I hope it will be helpful for the people who was bedevilled by the same problem.